# Gradient для Векторных изображений в XML

Tags: android, xml, svg, градиент, vector-drawable

Имею векторное изображение в фигме[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но при конвертации в `Android studio` в `XML` выходит это изображение: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проще говоря теряеться **слой тени** и теперь по краям нет тени вовсе. Как сделать так чтобы цвет даной вектороной картинки был по градиенту?
XML код векторного изображение в Android Studio

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="32dp"
    android:height="32dp"
    android:viewportWidth="32"
    android:viewportHeight="32">
  <group>
    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h32v32h-32z"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M11.5692,14.5455H26.3384H27.8153C29.2923,14.5455 30.7692,16 30.7692,17.4545V29.0909C30.7692,30.8364 28.7999,31.7576 27.8153,32H4.1846C1.8215,32 1.2307,30.0606 1.2307,29.0909V17.4545C1.2307,16 2.7076,14.5455 4.1846,14.5455H5.6615C5.6615,13.2851 5.6384,11.7517 5.6615,10.1818C5.6615,8 5.6615,7.2727 7.1384,4.3636C8.6153,1.4546 13.0461,0 15.9999,0C20.4307,0 23.3846,2.1818 24.8615,4.3636C25.8588,5.837 26.2248,7.414 26.3146,9.1822C26.3427,9.7338 25.8907,10.1818 25.3384,10.1818H21.4307C20.8784,10.1818 20.4357,9.7299 20.3151,9.191C19.9808,7.698 18.8493,5.8182 15.9999,5.8182C12.4553,5.8182 11.5692,8.7273 11.5692,10.1818V14.5455Z"
        android:fillColor="@color/brown_active"/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

Нашел [приблизительный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872114/can-gradientcolor-be-used-to-define-a-gradient-for-a-fill-or-stroke-entirely-in/40927551#40927551) на другом стеке но он мне не особо подходит так как Контур идет за векторным изображением и увеличевает высоту и ширину изображения

**SVG**

```html
  <svg viewBox="55 120 30 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <filter id="filter0_i_164_3914" x="54" y="120" width="32" height="34" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset dy="2"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.14 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow_164_3914"/>
        </filter>
        <g filter="url(#filter0_i_164_3914)">
            <mask id="mask2_164_3914" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="54" y="120" width="32" height="32">
                <rect x="54" y="120" width="32" height="32" fill="#D58900"/>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#mask2_164_3914)">
                <path d="M65.5694 134.545H80.3387H81.8156C83.2925 134.545 84.7694 136 84.7694 137.455V149.091C84.7694 150.836 82.8002 151.758 81.8156 152H58.1848C55.8217 152 55.231 150.061 55.231 149.091V137.455C55.231 136 56.7079 134.545 58.1848 134.545H59.6617C59.6617 133.285 59.6387 131.752 59.6617 130.182C59.6617 128 59.6617 127.273 61.1386 124.364C62.6156 121.455 67.0463 120 70.0002 120C74.431 120 77.3848 122.182 78.8617 124.364C79.8591 125.837 80.225 127.414 80.3149 129.182C80.3429 129.734 79.8909 130.182 79.3387 130.182H75.431C74.8787 130.182 74.436 129.73 74.3153 129.191C73.981 127.698 72.8495 125.818 70.0002 125.818C66.4556 125.818 65.5694 128.727 65.5694 130.182V134.545Z" fill="#D58900"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

P.S.: **сетку в первом рисунке прошу не учитывать**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801798/12656388 - здесь гуру SVG дает ответ на ваш вопрос, это не такая простая задача, как я понял. Я не знаю, поддерживаются ли SVG-фильтры в android. Попробуйте. Добавьте тогда и код исходного вектора.

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, код "векторного" изображения в Фигме, где эти тени есть.

Comment: @Leonid добавил SVG код

Comment: Да, но в этом коде нет тени. А где она есть?

Comment: ВОПРОС ОТКРЫТ
Нужно сделать тень в XML от Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих и мучительных експериментов я нашел ответ **вот в этих статьях**

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-gradients-part1/

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-gradients-part1-2/

Они полностью отвечают на мой вопрос

Спасибо большое @Alexandr_TT и @Leonid за помощь с SVG

На случай если пропадет куда то блог

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:width="96dp"
  android:height="96dp"
  android:viewportHeight="100"
  android:viewportWidth="100">
 
  <path
    android:pathData="M1,1 H99 V99 H1Z"
    android:strokeColor="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    android:strokeWidth="2">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient
        android:centerX="50"
        android:centerY="50"
        android:type="sweep">
        <item
          android:color="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
          android:offset="0.0" />
        <item
          android:color="?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:offset="1.0" />
 
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
</vector>
```

Comment: Так вам удалось загрузить весь тот гигантский SVG файл в андроид?

Comment: Как я понял из статьи, рассматриваются проблемы переноса градиентов линейных, радиальных, конических из svg в android. У вас добавляется проблема `<linearGradient id="paint145_linear_164_3914" x1="618.5" y1="3252.2" x2="617.6" y2="3301.7"` - 145 градиентов с абсолютным позиционированием gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> То есть вам нужно будет вручную переписывать в команды android ещё и позиции градиентов. И так 145 раз.  Основная проблема ещё фильтры и `mask-type:alpha` они тоже абсолютно позиционированы и их тоже надо переписывать. Не знаю, поддерживает ли маски и фильтры android

Comment: может вам лучше **обратиться к дизайнеру, чтобы сделать на каждую иконку отдельный SVG файл.** Наверняка у дизайнера сохранился исходник. По крайней мере с одним файлом на одну иконку будет легче работать при переводе в android/ Не будет индивидуального позиционирования в зависимости от положения отдельной иконки на общем полотне SVG/ Иначе вам надо будет переписывать, переделывать в ручную файл 800к с тысячами строк. Так как и `rect` `circle` и другие элементы имеют абсолютное позиционирование, разные координаты для каждой иконки

Comment: @Alexandr_TT гиганский файл как не грузи все равно он будет размитый как растр в студии

Comment: это понятно, надеюсь другие  мои комментарии выше полезны? Обратитесь к дизайнеру. Я действительно оч. сочувствую вам, в какую жесткую мясорубку вас бросили с такой работой

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!! Вы мне реально очень помоги понять в чем проблема. Дизайнер и виновата и невиновата одновременно. Виновата что сделала тени и закрепила их где то в другом месте, но явно не виновна в том что даже правильно скопированна картинка с тенью неправильно конвертирується Android Studio. Так что тут она явно не виновна нужно искать другие методы конвертации или лучше уже что бы Android studio писала приложухи а Unreal или Unity писали игры.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте в исходнике svg файла **удалить** `clipPath`

```
<clipPath>
    <path d="M0,0h32v32h-32z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
  </clipPath>
```

`clipPath` не нужен, возможно из-за него исчезает слой тени по краям.

Смотрите, что получается, вот видимо  так выглядел исходник svg без clipPath:

Красная рамка это граница холста svg - `32x32`

```js
console.log(path.getBBox())
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="border:1px solid red;" >  

<path id="path" fill="#D58900" d="M11.5692,14.5455H26.3384H27.8153C29.2923,14.5455 30.7692,16 30.7692,17.4545V29.0909C30.7692,30.8364 28.7999,31.7576 27.8153,32H4.1846C1.8215,32 1.2307,30.0606 1.2307,29.0909V17.4545C1.2307,16 2.7076,14.5455 4.1846,14.5455H5.6615C5.6615,13.2851 5.6384,11.7517 5.6615,10.1818C5.6615,8 5.6615,7.2727 7.1384,4.3636C8.6153,1.4546 13.0461,0 15.9999,0C20.4307,0 23.3846,2.1818 24.8615,4.3636C25.8588,5.837 26.2248,7.414 26.3146,9.1822C26.3427,9.7338 25.8907,10.1818 25.3384,10.1818H21.4307C20.8784,10.1818 20.4357,9.7299 20.3151,9.191C19.9808,7.698 18.8493,5.8182 15.9999,5.8182C12.4553,5.8182 11.5692,8.7273 11.5692,10.1818V14.5455Z" />

</svg>
```

Добавляем clip-path:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
<defs>
  <clipPath id="cp">
    <path d="M0,0h32v32h-32z" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>

<path clip-path="url(#cp)" fill="#D58900" d="M11.5692,14.5455H26.3384H27.8153C29.2923,14.5455 30.7692,16 30.7692,17.4545V29.0909C30.7692,30.8364 28.7999,31.7576 27.8153,32H4.1846C1.8215,32 1.2307,30.0606 1.2307,29.0909V17.4545C1.2307,16 2.7076,14.5455 4.1846,14.5455H5.6615C5.6615,13.2851 5.6384,11.7517 5.6615,10.1818C5.6615,8 5.6615,7.2727 7.1384,4.3636C8.6153,1.4546 13.0461,0 15.9999,0C20.4307,0 23.3846,2.1818 24.8615,4.3636C25.8588,5.837 26.2248,7.414 26.3146,9.1822C26.3427,9.7338 25.8907,10.1818 25.3384,10.1818H21.4307C20.8784,10.1818 20.4357,9.7299 20.3151,9.191C19.9808,7.698 18.8493,5.8182 15.9999,5.8182C12.4553,5.8182 11.5692,8.7273 11.5692,10.1818V14.5455Z" />
   <path d="M0,0h32v32h-32z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Теперь слой clip-path полностью накрывает слой  svg с изображением.
Можно предположить, что это одна из возможных причин исчезновения тени по краям.

Comment: @Leonid вполне возможно и твой вариант с CSS, но я видел и не раз, как clipPath при определенном стечении настроек просто убивает градиенты и фильтры. Вот, набросали автору идей, пусть пробует, экспериментирует.

Comment: Ясно, я сам не понял ответ, значит)) Пусть пробует, но это уже не первый раз, когда из Фигмы на выходе SVG ломается. Пробовал там поковыряться в инструментах разработчика, которые они скрывают тщательно, и ничего путного не нашел. Вычленить код SVG не реально, по-моему.

Comment: @Leonid и я не пойму роста мировой популярности этой "Фиг**н**и"  Казалось, чего может быть проще нарисовать в векторном редакторе и экспортировать в Android Studio

Comment: Я так понял, что там макеты страниц дизайнеры составляют, а потом дают верстальщикам, которые пытаются просто взять куски шедевров и перенести в SVG)) Может и нет))) Я тоже мало знаком, но штука популярная.

Comment: @Leonid ну да, дизайнеры оставляют макеты в растре, потом после конвертации в вектор получаются двойные контуры, логично, ведь как-то надо отразить толщину линий из растра в вектор. Потом просят анимировать, а это невозможно так как контур двойной, приходится перерисовывать в одиночные контуры. Короче хотели, как лучше, а получилось, как всегда.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT удалил слой `clip-path` но єто ничего не поменяло вовсе

Comment: @VladBulan нужно искать дальше. Попробуйте исходник SVG сюда разместить

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я уже добавил исходник SVG в вопрос

Comment: @VladBulan не заметил, работаю над другим ответом . А градиентов нет же в исходнике? Нужно в него градиенты добавить или фильтры, которые дают тень и скормить этот файл Android Studio без посредника figma

Comment: КРЧ суть в чем когда я качаю много картинок с фигмы в формате свг то тень не падает на сайте https://www.svgviewer.dev/ вот сейчас выпишу несколько строк которые отвечают за тот замок и скину

Comment: @Alexandr_TT у меня есть код всех кнопок из тенями, но я их не могу отделить и скинуть так как не знаю что там можно отделить+ там 6 тисяч строк + это корпоративная тайна скорее всего

Comment: @VladBulan сочувствую, заставляют работать, заставляют хранить тайну, а не объясняют как правильно делать.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT та не за тайну я не знаю, только первую неделю работаю стажером. Поэтому не хочу что бы из-за этой оплошности меня уволили, и так 3 месяца работу искал(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131391/discussion-between-vlad-bulan-and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 3):

Оптимизировал исходник => [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) за счет уменьшения знаков после десятичной запятой.

Физический размер иконки замка узнал с помощью

```
<script>
console.log(lock.getBBox())
</script>
```

где lock это - `ID` path замка

Установил эти цифры в шапке svg файла.

Чёрная рамка - это граница холста SVG, после настройки её надо удалить `style="border:1px solid"`  Немного подкорректировал размеры в шапке SVG, чтобы фигура не касалась рамки.   Это гарантирует, что не будет обрезов, в случае выхода фигуры за холст SVG/
Размер иконки видимо проектировался `32х32px`
Здесь увеличил для просмотра в 10 раз - `width="300" height="330"`

```html
<svg width="300" height="330" viewBox="55 119.5 30 33" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 style="border:1px solid">
    <!-- строка в редакторе 19 -26 -->
  <g filter="url(#filter0_i_164_3914)">
    <mask id="mask2_164_3914" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="54" y="120" width="32" height="32">
      <path fill="#D58900" d="M54 120h32v32H54z"/>
    </mask>
    <g mask="url(#mask2_164_3914)">
      <path id="lock" d="M65.6 134.5h16.2c1.5 0 3 1.5 3 3V149c0 1.7-2 2.7-3 2.9H58.2c-2.4 0-3-2-3-3v-11.5c0-1.5 1.5-3 3-3h1.5v-4.3c0-2.2 0-3 1.4-5.8 1.5-3 6-4.4 8.9-4.4 4.4 0 7.4 2.2 8.9 4.4a9 9 0 0 1 1.4 4.8c0 .5-.4 1-1 1h-3.9c-.5 0-1-.5-1-1a4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.4-3.4c-3.5 0-4.4 3-4.4 4.4v4.3Z" fill="#D58900"/>
    </g>
  </g>
<defs> 
             <!-- строка в редакторе 2906 -->
<filter id="filter0_i_164_3914" x="54" y="120" width="32" height="34" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="2"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.14 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow_164_3914"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg> 

<script>
console.log(lock.getBBox())
</script>
```

Comment: Весь оптимизатор можно свести к `path.setAttribute('d', path.getAttribute('d').replace(/[\d.]+/g, m => Number(m).toFixed(2)));`, где path - `document.querySelector('path');` )) Ну и `toFixed(2)` оставляет два знака после точки. Ошибка в консоли, `lock` не объявлена.

Comment: @Leonid Спасибо Леонид, этот код просто сводит с ума, продолжу распутывать клубки